# Java Icon File not showing image

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am using a Imagebox JFrame to add image, I want to change image in runtime so I add following code but nothing is displayed.

```
 javax.swing.JFileChooser filechooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
        filechooser.showDialog(this,"ok");
        File f =  filechooser.getSelectedFile();
        txt_Image.setText(f.getName());        
        FileName = f.getPath()+f.getName();
        Image im= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(FileName);
        ImageIcon receivedIcon =null;
        receivedIcon.setImage(im);
        imagebox1.setimageFile(receivedIcon);
```

the image box code is below

```
public class imagebox extends JPanel {
    public void setimageFile(Icon icon) {
       imageFile=icon;
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (imageFile != null) {            
            Image imageF=  ((ImageIcon)imageFile).getImage();
           g.drawImage(imageF, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        } else {
            g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.drawLine(0, getHeight(), getWidth(), 0);
        }
    }
    private Icon imageFile = null;
```

so why no error showing but I cant get any image in my imagebox

Comment: It's hard to believe that the following snippet of code isn't generating a `NullPointerException`: `ImageIcon receivedIcon =null;
        receivedIcon.setImage(im);
`

Comment: ImageIcon receivedIcon = new ImageIcon();
        receivedIcon.setImage(im);  
also tried this

Comment: WHY IS YOUR NAME IN ALL CAPS?  IS YOUR KEYBOARD BROKEN OR DO YOU JUST LIKE **YELLING** AT STRANGERS ON THE NET?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: *"extremely sorry"*  I would prefer you edit the handle (name) used on Stack Overflow, rather than apologize.

Comment: i am so sorry what was wrong is 
i have to use 

      Image im= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(f.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageIcon receivedIcon = new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
            receivedIcon.setImage(im);
         receivedIcon.setImage(im);


f.getAbsolutePath() instead of FileName = f.getPath()+f.getName();

i am verry sorry for the troubles create to u,
and thanks all of u for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageIcon receivedIcon = null;
receivedIcon.setImage(im);
```

changed to

```
ImageIcon receivedIcon = new ImageIcon();
receivedIcon.setImage(im);
```

Comment: already tried 
also i tried this ImageIcon receivedIcon = new ImageIcon();
        receivedIcon.setImage(im);
        imagebox1.setimageFile(receivedIcon);
lb_Title.setIcon(receivedIcon);
repaint();  //no result

Comment: i am so sorry what was wrong is 
i have to use 

      Image im= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(f.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageIcon receivedIcon = new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
            receivedIcon.setImage(im);
         receivedIcon.setImage(im);


f.getAbsolutePath() instead of FileName = f.getPath()+f.getName();

i am verry sorry for the troubles create to u,
and thanks all of u for helping me

Answer (score 2):

if you only to display the `Images` then better would be to use [Icon/ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) directly, (to avoiding `Casting` or whatever) put this Icon to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) instead of to the [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

if you want change your `Icon` on Runtime, then you code would be

```
myLabel.setIcon(myIcon);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

this code must be done on the EDT, otherwise you have to wrap a.m. code lines into [invokeLater()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: revalidate(); can u explain it

Comment: so nice that you changed name, basically for success is enought use of `myLabel.setIcon(myIcon);` but in most completed GUI layed by standard http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html , you have test that if you code required these code lines, in case that you set there setSize() with setBounds(), then forgot about last two code lines

Comment: i am so sorry what was wrong is 
i have to use 

      Image im= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(f.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageIcon receivedIcon = new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
            receivedIcon.setImage(im);
         receivedIcon.setImage(im);


f.getAbsolutePath() instead of FileName = f.getPath()+f.getName();

i am verry sorry for the troubles create to u,
and thanks all of u for helping me